# How to use autofac inside a parallel.foreach loop

Tags: c#, webforms, autofac

Trying to change a foreach statement to a parallel.foreach. with autofac.

My solution is a webforms site that I am trying to add AutoFac to. The class that I am having a problem with is working with Autofac, with a standard foreach. I would like to transition to a Parrallel.foreach. All the examples show a container.BeginLIfetimeScope() but no information on what container is or how to new one up.

```
Parallel.ForEach(items, item =>
{
     // Note I'm calling container.BeginLifetimeScope() inside the ForEach
     using (var parallelScope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
     {
         var aDataService = parallelScope.Resolve<IaDataService>();
         aDataService.SomeProcessing();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Side note, but in a server application you probably shouldn't use the Parallel.* methods.

Comment: It's not clear - the title says that the question is about how to use it in a parallel.foreach loop, but the question says that it's about what a container is and how to create it. Whichever one is the question, that should be in the title of the question.

Comment: The container is autofac. That is why the question is how to use autofac in a parallel.foreach.

Comment: Could you edit the question to be clearer? It sounds like either a) you have existing code with Autofac which works, but doesn't when you put it inside a Parallel block, or b) you're looking for general advice on how to use an Autofac container, or both. If (a) could you report the specific error you are seeing and include the wire-up for the container. If (b), there's plenty of documentation it would be worth reading first-up, e.g. https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/index.html

Comment: a) yes b)yes how to use an Autofac container inside a Parallel block.  a) no error as I cant get the code to compile. where does container come from. b) that is were this code is from. yet no discussion on how you get the container in a class, in a webforms application

Comment: The working code you refer to *must* already include a definition of the container, and the basic usage (but not best practice) is no different whether inside a `Parallel` block or a `foreach`. How to construct a container is certainly included in the documentation too. Not sure if I'm missing something there. Further documentation about better practice when using WebForms is here: https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webforms.html. I'll provide an answer as best I can but it would be helpful to include more info in future: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

The code below compiles and works for me. Given:

```
public interface IaDataService
{
    void SomeProcessing(object obj);
}

public class DataService : IaDataService
{
    public void SomeProcessing(object obj)
    {

    }
}
```

We could do something like:

```
var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
containerBuilder.RegisterType<DataService>()
    .As<IaDataService>();
var container = containerBuilder.Build();

var items = new List<object>{"abc", 123};
Parallel.ForEach(items, item =>
{
    // Note I'm calling container.BeginLifetimeScope() inside the ForEach
    using (var parallelScope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
    {
        var aDataService = parallelScope.Resolve<IaDataService>();
        aDataService.SomeProcessing(item);
    }
});
```

Using WebForms, you're likely better off using the specific integration for it:
[Autofac WebForms](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webforms.html), and there are other best practice questions about thread safety, generating new scopes for each item you generate etc. But the above should be enough to get started.